# Scala: Why do we need to keep type members in the package object?

Tags: scala, architecture, finatra

When I was studying `Twitter Finatra` (v2.1.1) sources, I found a very odd architecture. They put `type`s into `package object`s. See examples below:

```
package object marshalling {
  @deprecated("MessageBodyManager is an internal class. Use the HttpMockResponses trait to gain access to a testResponseBuilder", "")
  type MessageBodyManager = com.twitter.finatra.http.internal.marshalling.MessageBodyManager

  @deprecated("Use com.twitter.finatra.http.marshalling.DefaultMessageBodyReader", "")
  type DefaultMessageBodyReader = com.twitter.finatra.http.marshalling.DefaultMessageBodyReader

  // ...
}
```

Or this

```
package object filters {
  @deprecated("Use com.twitter.finatra.http.filters.AccessLoggingFilter", "")
  type AccessLoggingFilter = com.twitter.finatra.http.filters.AccessLoggingFilter[Request]

  @deprecated("Use com.twitter.finatra.http.filters.CommonFilters", "")
  type CommonFilters = com.twitter.finatra.http.filters.CommonFilters

  // ...
}
```

I don't understand what is the purpose of such odd design. Why do we need to create a type alias (type member) as in the examples? Just to say that  class is deprecated?

Comment: I guess they moved the classes from one package to another and in order to not break source compatibility they introduced these deprecated type aliases.

Comment: But they suggest to use the deprecated class instead of deprecated :)

Comment: `Use com.twitter.finatra.http.filters.AccessLoggingFilter` instead of `com.twitter.finatra.http.filters.AccessLoggingFilter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was done in a [refactoring commit](https://github.com/twitter/finatra/commit/c080187bdb9e14ef3fa442bbf5a90af7dccad7fb#diff-d2b3255298208288007bf7292b77b1ac). You can see there that multiple classes have been moved to new packages, and the type aliases and deprecations were added. For example, `DefaultMessageBodyReader` was [here](https://github.com/twitter/finatra/commit/d0ea02a526478e95f3687610fb77013f89fee7b3#diff-d2b3255298208288007bf7292b77b1ac) and then got moved into the internal package. In its original place the alias and deprecation were left.